# how to use linq to return all ints in another set of ints for this scenario?

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following scenario:

```
1. int[] contentPermissions
2. Dictionary<int, int[]> userPermssions
```

In #2 above, the key is the user ID and the value is an int[] of user permission ID's. What would be a good way to write a lambda function to return all user ID's which have a permission id which matches at least 1 permission in contentPermissions?

**UPDATE**

Does this look like a pretty good solution?:

```
  var userIdsWithPermissions = userPermissions.Where(
            x => x.Value.Intersect(contentPermissions).Count() > 1)
            .Select(x => x.Key).ToArray();
```

Comment: You tell *us* if it is working properly or not, and if not, what about it isn't working as it should.

Comment: You're answer makes a lot more sense than mine. Little bit of a D'Oh moment for me.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is almost correct, but instead of "Count() > 1" should be "Count() > 0".

```
var userIdsWithPermissions = userPermssions.Where(
                    x => x.Value.Intersect(contentPermissions).Count() > 0)
                    .Select(x => x.Key).ToArray();
```

Another solution could be this:

```
var userIdsWithPermissions = from u in userPermssions
                             where contentPermissions.Any(p => u.Value.Contains(p))
                             select u;
```

Both producing same output. Last one is faster taking just 4 ms, against 22 ms of the Intersect solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to use a `Contains()` function. A slightly different option using `Any()`

```
        List<int> contentPermissions = new List<int>();
        Dictionary<int, List<int>> userPermssions = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();

        var A = userPermssions.Where(m => m.Value.Any(n => contentPermissions.Contains(n))).Select(m => m.Key).ToList();
```

Comment: Why is this downvoted? I have the exact solution as derloopkat

Comment: Not sure why. You use a pipeline so it might be problem with performance. However your code does the job. My answer also was downvoted. I'm going to upvote yours because it's correct as far as I can see.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method:

```
public int[] GetUserIDArrayByPermission(int permission)
{
  var dicUserPermission=userPermssions.Where(i => i.Value.Contains(permission));
 int[] userIDArray=dicUserPermission.Select(p => p.Key).ToArray();
 return userIDArray;
}
```

UPDATE:

```
public int[] GetUserIDArrayByContentPermissions()
{            
  var dicUserPermission = userPermssions.Where(i => i.Value.Count(p=>contentPermissions.Contains(p))>0).ToList();
  int[] userIDArray = dicUserPermission.Select(p => p.Key).ToArray();
  return userIDArray;
}
```

Comment: OP asked for a code that "return all user ID's which have a permission id which matches at least 1 permission in contentPermissions". This code returns all user Ids with one permission provided as argument. This is not what was asked.

Comment: @derloopkat , yes,  It was my fault and wrote new method